# NextJS com TypeScript e styled-components não está funcionando

Tags: typescript, next.js, styled-components

Estou tentando usar o *styled-components* na minha aplicação NextJS, mas sempre retorna um erro, não entendo porque nao esta funcionando.

para iniciar o projeto eu [usei o comando](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-typescript-styled-components):

```
   npx create-next-app --example with-typescript-styled-components client
```

meu código:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Link from 'next/link';
import styled from 'styled-components'

const joinOuterContainer = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    height: 100vh;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #1A1A1D;
`

export default function SignIn() {
  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  const [room, setRoom] = useState('');
  
  return(
    <joinOuterContainer>
      <div className="joinInnerContainer">
        <h1 className="heading">Join</h1>
        <div>
          <input placeholder="Name" className="joinInput" type="text" onChange={(event) => setName(event.target.value)} />
        </div>
        <div>
          <input placeholder="Room" className="joinInput mt-20" type="text" onChange={(event) => setRoom(event.target.value)} />
        </div>
        <Link href={`/ chat? name = $ { name } & room = $ { room } `}>
          <button
            className={'button mt-20'}
            type="submit"
            onClick={(e: any) => (!name || !room ? e.preventDefault() : null)}
            >
            Sign In
          </button>
        </Link>
      </div>
    </joinOuterContainer>
  );
}
```

```
Erro: StyledComponent<"div", any, {}, never>
Property 'joinOuterContainer' does not exist on type 'JSX.IntrinsicElements'.ts(2339)
```

ele diz que o erro está na tag `<joinOuterContainer></joinOuterContainer>` e na declaração da constante `joinOuterContainer` (linhas 5,19 e 38, respectivamente)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Você deve utilizar a convenção de nomes `PascalCase` para nomear componentes "próprios" (criados por você, o programador).

Quando essa convenção não é propriamente seguida, o compilador do TypeScript entende que você está se referindo a uma *tag* do HTML, o que não é, evidentemente, o caso. Como uma *tag* HTML `joinOuterContainer` não existe, um erro é levantado.

Quando utiliza-se a convenção `PascalCase`, o compilador busca pelo componente no escopo do código em execução.

Portanto, altere o nome do seu componente de `joinOuterContainer` para `JoinOuterContainer`.

Comment: Muito Obrigado!!!!! Resolveu o problema! muito obrigado!!!